# Can anyone tell me why nothing is displayed on the scope?

Tags: microprocessor, proteus

This design isn't working, nothing is displayed on the scope.

```
CODE SEGMENT
ORG 100H
                                       
mov al,37h

mov dx,6h

out dx,al


mov ax,1000h

mov dx,0h

out dx,al 

mov dx,0h

mov al,ah

out dx,al 

                      
        CODE ENDS

END
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like address decoding issue. The chip sees both IO and MEM accesses, so even memory reads happening due to code execution can put the timer chip into unknown state.

Comment: Does the scope actually display on screen with no signals? Or does it just not display the scope itself?

Comment: MCG the scope is displayed but without any signal

Comment: Any one Can Help??